# anyone know how can i achieve this kind of loading screen for dashboard admin panel website using react?

Tags: reactjs, flutter, admin, panel, dashboard

[youtube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkMjR.gif)

i have tried finding but no luck. I am using react to build a dashboard admin panel.

any useful video or other sources would be helpful.

Comment: You can create two reactJs components and use them by setting state. While user is being authenticated you can render <Loading/> component and when it is authenticated or connection is established you can render <Dashboard /> component.

Comment: Will this help? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-skeleton

Answer (score 1):

The technique you describe is a 'skeleton' loader of the component - you'll want to set the loading state of the component

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

and use that in your component to either render the skeleton or not.

see:

https://material-ui.com/components/skeleton/

https://skeletonreact.com/

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/04/skeleton-screens-react/

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is an example of Skeleton components

You can use ready components from Antd or Material UI

[Antd Skeleton](https://ant.design/components/skeleton/)

[Material UI Skeleton](https://material-ui.com/components/skeleton/)

Answer (score 0):

This is called "Skeleton Loading Screen".
You can find some of these using Material-UI Library, but you shouldn't use MUI for ONLY this purpose (I do recommend it, it has really nice reusable and customable components).

You can find some more information about skeletons screens [here.](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/04/skeleton-screens-react/)

Answer (score 0):

there is a react package for this kind of loading:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-skeleton